# query on AsyncApexJob does not query for all rows

Tags: query, asyncapexjob

I am actually querying into the AsyncApexJob for a particuler date using a range, but the query isn't returning me the job required, where im sure that i launched my batch on that particular day. My questions are :

1. Is there some kind of archived batch jobs where in a normal query, we can't get jobs completed with 60 days or something like this,just like it does for activities ?
2. If yes, then how can i retrieve archived completed jobs ? I tried using the all rows but of no avail.

Here is my sample query, which return on more recent dates :

```
 select id,JobType,CompletedDate,MethodName,Status 
 from AsyncApexJob 
 where CompletedDate > 2015-08-10T00:00:00Z 
 and CompletedDate < 2015-08-11T00:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the job is no more available after 7 days